# Null BufferedImage when using PDFBox in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, pdf, pdfbox, javax.imageio

I am trying to use PDFBox in a Java application running as a Webservelet on Tomcat 7 and Java 6. I have successfully gotten my code to run as a compiled JAR that works on several different test files that I supply to the application. However, when I try to use it as a WAR file on Tomcat, it throws several errors.

PDFBox seems to be unable to access the images in the PDF file I provide to the application. The PDF file is loaded from disk in a directory read/write accessible to the tomcat instance. The structure of the PDF seems to be detected by PDFBox. However, when I try to access images within the PDF using the code below, `getRGBImage()` returns `null`. This is only true on the server, however, as the same code successfully returns a `BufferedImage` when run as a JAR.

```
PDResources resources = page.getResources();
Map<String, PDXObject> pageImages = resources.getXObjects();
if (pageImages != null) {
    Iterator<String> imageIter = pageImages.keySet().iterator();
    while( imageIter.hasNext() ) {
        String key = (String)imageIter.next();
        PDXObject xobject = pageImages.get( key );
            PDXObjectImage image = null;
            if (xobject instanceof PDXObjectImage) {
                image = (PDXObjectImage) xobject;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        // Save image as a separate file
        BufferedImage pdfImage = image.getRGBImage();
        if (pdfImage == null) {
            logger.error("Null image.");
            continue;
        }
        File outFile = new File(this.temporary + "out" + this.imageIdx + ".png");
        ImageIO.write(pdfImage, "png", outFile);
    }
}
```

If allowed to continue on to `ImageIO.write()`, PDFBox will throw an exception about the `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDPixelMap` object being empty. What could be causing this issue?

EDIT: The following shows the exception output by the above code if `continue;` is removed.

```
3298 [PDFWorker:0] ERROR org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDPixelMap  - Something went wrong ... the pixelmap doesn't contain any data.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at asdf.ImageOCRProcessor.doHOCR(ImageOCRProcessor.java:69)
    at asdf.PDFExtractor.endPage(PDFExtractor.java:329)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:457)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:379)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:335)
    at asdf.PDFExtractor.processByParts(PDFExtractor.java:135)
```

Comment: Please check whether you are using the same jars, e.g. levigo and the jai_imageio. Please post also the log messages.

Comment: The jars used for the webapp are pulled from the same source as for the code packaged as a jar. Edited original post.

Comment: What version are you using? The getImages() call is deprecated due to synchronisation problems. Please get the latest version (1.8.6), and use getXObjects() instead. [See the sample class ExtractImages for how to do it.](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/1.8/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/ExtractImages.java?view=markup&sortby=date)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I've updated to 1.8.6 and the getXObjects() call. As before, it works correctly when using the code as a jar but not when packaged into a webapp.

Comment: Now the only advice I can give you is to open an issue in PDFBOX JIRA, include a "minimal" but fully runnable project to reproduce the issue with tomcat, and a PDF.